# Mysql: how to find users that currently in the room?

Tags: mysql

I have table `entrances` that logs times when users came into the room and came out of the room. Something like that:

```
user   |   action    |    time
-------------------------------------------
Ivan   |   in        |  2016-08-28 12:00:00 
John   |   in        |  2016-08-28 12:00:01
Ann    |   in        |  2016-08-28 12:00:02
Ivan   |   out       |  2016-08-28 12:00:03
Ivan   |   in        |  2016-08-28 12:00:04
Ann    |   out       |  2016-08-28 12:00:05
Ivan   |   out       |  2016-08-28 12:00:06
Mike   |   in        |  2016-08-28 12:00:07
John   |   out       |  2016-08-28 12:00:08
Ann    |   out       |  2016-08-18 12:00:09
John   |   in        |  2016-08-18 12:00:10
John   |   out       |  2016-08-18 12:00:11
Ann    |   in        |  2016-08-18 12:00:12
```

Users actions are independent. Only is known is that first action is always `in` and user cannot `in` twice witout `out` (and reverse).

**My goal is to find all users that currently in room.**

I have two ideas:

1. select users that have no `out` after latest `in`
2. select users that has count `in` more that count `out`

How to implement this on mysql? Or any other ideas?

SQL for testing:

```
CREATE TABLE `entrances` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `action` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
INSERT INTO `entrances` (`id`, `user`, `action`, `time`) VALUES
(1, 'Ivan', 'in', '2016-08-28 12:00:00'),
(2, 'John', 'in', '2016-08-28 12:00:01'),
(3, 'Ann', 'in', '2016-08-28 12:00:02'),
(4, 'Ivan', 'out', '2016-08-28 12:00:03'),
(5, 'Ivan', 'in', '2016-08-28 12:00:04'),
(6, 'Ann', 'out', '2016-08-28 12:00:05'),
(7, 'Ivan', 'out', '2016-08-28 12:00:06'),
(8, 'Mike', 'in', '2016-08-28 12:00:07'),
(9, 'John', 'out', '2016-08-28 12:00:08'),
(10, 'Ann', 'out', '2016-08-28 12:00:09'),
(11, 'John', 'in', '2016-08-28 12:00:10'),
(12, 'John', 'out', '2016-08-28 12:00:11'),
(13, 'Ann', 'in', '2016-08-28 12:00:12');
ALTER TABLE `entrances` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. First get the last action `time` from each `user` in the subquery
2. Then join against that subquery to have only the last record for each `user`
3. Then take only those records having the `action = in` with the `where` clause

Like this

```
select e.*
from entrances e
join
(
   select user, max(time) as mtime
   from entrances
   group by user
) t on t.user = e.user 
   and t.mtime = e.time
where e.action = 'in'
```

Comment: `where action = 'in'` should throw an error, since it is duplicate in the original and joined table

Comment: No. The joined table does not select this column

Comment: In the case that a user enters and exits in the same second the result will be wrong because there would be two rows with the same `t.mtime = e.time` but you would still get the `e.action = 'in'`row in the result

Comment: @DimitriL.: First this is absolutely not likely to happen. And Second the result would not be wrong. It would be unknown and the system that makes the records would be wrong because that should never happen. Looking for a reason to downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Join all row with the action `out` and select the ones that have no `out` action or the `in` action is newer

```
SELECT * FROM entrances e
LEFT JOIN entrances e1 ON e.user = e1.user AND e1.action = 'out'
WHERE e.action = 'in' AND (e1.user IS NULL OR e.time > e1.time)
GROUP BY e.user, e.action
```

Comment: But the joined table has no records with `action = in` since you do `ON ... AND e1.action = 'out'`

Comment: That's right. You only select the `out` records from the e1 and the `in` records from the e table and show the ones that have a greater time for an entrance or have no `out` action. `WHERE e.action = 'in' AND (e1.user IS NULL OR e.time > e1.time)`

Comment: This also works if there are more actions than just `in` and `out` whereas the accepted answer does not.

Answer (score 0):

I will try something like this however it's better to test on real data.

```
select user from entrances e inner join 
(select user, count(*) cnt from entrances where action='in') as e_in 
on e.user=e_in.user left join 
(select user, count(*) cnt from entrances where action='out') as e_out 
on e.user=e_out.user
where e_out.user is null or (e_in.cnt - e_out.cnt) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql implementation of my idea number 1:

```
SELECT e.* FROM entrances e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM entrances WHERE e.user=user AND action="out" AND time > (
        SELECT MAX(time) FROM entrances WHERE e.user=user AND action="in"
    )
)
```

This works literally as written: find users that have no `out` after last `in`. Utilizes [NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html%20%22NOT%20EXISTS%22%20feature.) feature.  Advantage is readability without magic, plain algorythm.